# Google Earth API - 3d Model Overlays

Tags: google-earth, collada

Does anyone know why the google earth api only supports COLLADA (.dae) 3d model overlays and not kmz???

```
KmlModel  GEPlugin.createModel   (   string     id    )    

Creates a model. A model is a 3D object described in a COLLADA file. COLLADA files have a .dae file extension. Models are created in their own coordinate space and then located, positioned, and scaled in Google Earth.

Parameters:
     id  ID of the new KmlModel.
```

Is it possible to overlay kmz?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is because (Collada) 3D models and KML/KMZ files are fundamentally different - Collada contains most of all geometric drawing primitives while KML/KMZ files contain geocode. There are functions for both.

A KML or KMZ file is loaded into the DOM via the [KmlNetworkLink() function](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/kml.html#kmlnetworklink)

Answer (score 0):

KMZ is really a zip file, that sometimes contain a model in a COLLADA file. take a look here: http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/import-google-sketchup-kmz-models.php